# Rationale for oddly shaped SATA cable

Tags: power-supply, sata, cable

Background: I have a commission to build a desktop and put some of my stuff on it, but I'm a software guy and new to the construction/configuration of hardware.  I am not even sure how to check if this is a duplicate.

The power supply I got ([EVGA 750 G2](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00J01K3E8/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)) came with an impressive group of cables, but I am troubled about two of them. They have an odd shape, rather like a Greek delta.  See this photo...

[image]

There are three connectors which seem to double back on the first one. But this seems to go against the stack of HDD bays which is vertical. It looks like the other connections are for something in mid-air. The DVD writer fits in the top slot and the hard drive fits in a small purpose built rack on the bottom (the case is a [Raven Tower EATX](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0083VYLDA/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1)) so there's no apparent way the cable can service both of them.

Question: what is the rationale for this odd shape and how can it be deployed in a configuration?

I have another question about the cabling of an SSD drive which will be put forward separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of a typical Power cable for SATA storage devices that come with PSUs. Since you can have multiple storage drives in your case and you don't have to have a separate cable going in your PSU, designers have provided you with a single cable that can power multiple drives. you don't have to use all ports if you don't need them.

Here's an example of a cable that can power 5 storage drives:
[image]

Here's how those drives could look with such a cable: 
[image]

Have in mind that there have been issues with under-powering drives if you have all the ports used by demanding drives when they are under 100% load at the same time. This depends on the quality of the cable as well as on the PSU itself.

Comment: Great answer, but do you have a source or some further reading for the claim about underpowering drives?

Answer (score 1):

This cable seems to be designed to power three devices stacked together, by bending the smaller parts just like this:

[image: HDD stack with bent power cables]

Obviously, in your setup you will use the 3" 1/2 bays of the case. This setup I found on Google seems rather "hand-made" but you get the idea.

You will also need to stack your devices directly on top of each other (no space between them) because I'm not sure if the smaller parts of your cable are long enough to allow an empty bay.